# Large Arrays and Memory Usage

Tags: java, memory-management, arrays

There's a way around it but the "easy" way for my program to work would be putting a great deal of text into String variables.

I would have approximately 644 objects, each with their own String variable.  Each one of these variables would contain approximately 9,240 characters (including spaces).  Is this too much?

Comment: What do you mean by "too much"?   644*9240*2 is 11,901,120

Comment: If you see three hairs, is it too much? That depends on whether it's on someone's head, or in someone's bowl of soup ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In java characters are Unicode by default, so their size is 2B. Now:

```
2B * 9,240 chars = 18480B = ~18KB
```

Then

```
18480B * 644 variables = 11901120B = ~11MB
```

The total memory occupied by all the `String` objects is ~11MB.

If you don't have an old 64MB RAM i think it's acceptable

Comment: Java string takes more memory than the simple adddition of number of bytes taken by characters it contains.

Comment: @JunedAhsan I know, this is just an example, even if they take 5B instead of 2 it won't be a problem, as modern RAMs have a minimum of 512MB free space

Answer (score 1):

Simple calculations show that the total space required by such objects would be less than 12 MB - not a large amount of memory on most modern computer systems, with the exclusion of embedded Java platforms. To do the calculations, multiply the number of characters by two (because Java's `char` is a 16-bit number).